# ¿Como detectar si un color es parecido a otro en opencv?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

Lo mas probable es que la redacción de la pregunta no sea correcta, pero no se me ocurre como redactarla. Adobe Premiere Pro tiene la opción de pantalla verde y tu puedes decirle que borre el color que seleccionaste y todos los colores parecidos dentro de un rango (ej: tengo un verde y me borra ese verde y unos verdes mas claros y mas oscuros. Mi pregunta es si se puede hacer algo parecido(osea detectar todos los verdes por ej) en opencv con python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sí se puede, se llama **segmentación por color** te dejo un buen tutorial que habla de eso:
https://realpython.com/python-opencv-color-spaces/

De igual forma te dejo un buen [PDF](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Jose_Oncina3/publication/242214900_Algoritmos_de_busqueda_de_vecinos_mas_proximos_en_espacios_metricos/links/00b4952948536ea588000000/Algoritmos-de-busqueda-de-vecinos-mas-proximos-en-espacios-metricos.pdf) si quieres entender cómo funciona la parte algorítimica y matemática de la segmentación, no te tienes que leer todo, creo que las primeras páginas te darán más o menos una idea.

Comment: la idea de la zona de respuestas es colocar la forma de resolverlo, el dejar enlaces se considera de baja calidad; por favor lee [answer] edita esta pub. y añade lo relevante